# bash with expect: Help with accessing variables

Tags: bash, expect

I am writing a bash script with expect.
Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash    

set prompt 0  
set bash_spawn_id $spawn_id  


check_prompt(){  
expect -c "  
spawn telnet $IP $PORT1  
set telnet_spawn_id $spawn_id  

sleep 1  
send \"\r\"  
send \"\r\"  
expect {  
loader> {set spawn_id $bash_spawn_id ; set prompt 1;set spawn_id $telnet_spawn_id }  
}  
expect{  
Login> {set spawn_id $bash_spawn_id ; set prompt 2;set spawn_id $telnet_spawn_id }  
}  
"  
}
```

Basically check_prompt is a function that i am calling in my bash script. When called I am cecking for a certain prompt, if i see the prompt as loader> then set the bash variable prompt to 1 else set it to 2 if it sees Login> prompt. For moving into the bash context to access the variables i am going to set the appropriate spawn_id to access the variables.
But i am facing the error:

```
spawn telnet 1.2.1.7 2001  
can't read "telnet_spawn_id": no such variable  
    while executing  
"set telnet_spawn_id  "
```

### Solution:

After struggling for 2 hrs, I could finally achieve what i wanted :)
Thanks Eduardo for the help.  Here is the partial program, you can make out the rest easily:

```
#!/bin/bash  

check_prompt() {  
expect -c "    
log_user 0    
spawn telnet $IP $PORT1  
sleep 1  
send \"\r\"  
send \"\r\"  
expect {  
loader> {send_user \"1\" }  
Login> {send_user \"2\"}  
}  
" > tempfile  
read output < tempfile  
echo $output  
}    

chk_prompt() {  
check_prompt > prompt  
read output < prompt  
echo out=$output  
}
```

Basically I can redirecting output of the expect process, which prints either 1 or 2 depending on the prompts. I am suppressing other logs by setting `log_user` to zero. Rest is self explanatory :)
Let me know if you guys need any help :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638369/conditional-statament-inside-expect-command-called-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on expect, but I'm pretty sure you should be declaring your variables in bash using standard syntax like `prompt=0`, for example, instead of the set keyword which in bash sets internal shell options.

The error message you're getting is kind of misleading, but I'm tempted to say that `$spawn_id` being null (as you haven't really setted it previously, while still in bash) has something to do with it.

Comment: spawn_id is a builtin variable that stores the spawn id of the current process. So it is set whenever the process is spawned.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Could you post a full example? I mean: how are you calling this function?